# equivalence of arakelian set definition

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

A closed set $E$ without holes ( holes means bounded component of its complement) is said to be Arakelian if for every disc $D$  ( or compact sets in general) the union of all holes of $E \cup D $  are bounded.

A closed set $E$ without holes is Arakelian iff $\mathbb{C}\cup \{\infty\}\backslash E$ is locally connected at $\infty$ .

How we can prove that these two definitions are equivalent.

Comment: Do you have an intuition about whether one direction (implication) is easier than the other?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Can you explain it?